# Enable Publishing in 'Data Factory' mode

Tags: azure, github, repository, azure-data-factory

I have enabled Git on my Azure Data Factory. I have created my Git Repository also.
When I want to create a new Pipeline I have this message :

You have GIT enabled in your data factory. Publishing in 'Data Factory' mode is disabled. Please switch back to GIT mode to make further changes.
When I want to chose GitHub there is a popup "You do not have access to the repository"

How can I give access to repository?

[image]

Right now I have given below access to my user:

[image: c]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. What I did was to remove the GIT connection and then add it again. Then everything worked!

The git "setup" when creating the data factory seems not to work that well. Better to create the GIT connection later when the data factory is created.

To delete the git connection:

1. Go to "Data factory overview" (house icon)
2. Press the "git repo setting" in the top right -> delete :)

[image]

Comment: How did you create the git connection after?

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#connect-to-a-git-repository