# How to disconnect GitHub from Azure Data Factory V2 to enable "Copy data" Feature?

Tags: azure, github, azure-data-factory, azureportal

So the problem is that I created Azure Data Factory with git enabled on the portal. After the resource was validated and created, and after clicking on Author and Monitor, the "*Copy Data*" feature seems to be disabled as shown in the picture below:

[image]

When hovered on the "*Copy Data*": **This feature is disabled in 'Data Factory' mode as your factory has GIT enabled. Please switch to 'GIT' mode to use this.**

After clicking on the Manage, the disconnect button seems to be disabled again as shown in the picture below.
[image]
How do I enable the button and disconnect my GitHub to enable "*Copy data*" feature?

**Update:**
Nandan said to check on Author but it is disabled as well.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the GIT by disconnecting via Manage option as seen below:
[image]

But initially you would need to go to Author section to hover to drop down to change from Data factory mode to Git Mode:
[image]

The above images are via account which has access on GIT as well as ADF.

I logged in via an Account which has contributor access on ADF but no access on the repo and when I logged into ADF I got the below warning which got blocked in pop up of explorer :
[image]

And when I clicked on continue, and when I went to Manage section ; the disconnect option was disabled for me as seen below
[image]

So I added my account to Repo and after sometime I was able to manage the GIT in ADF

Comment: As you can see in my question (with screenshot) that the 'Disconnect' button is disabled. It means that I am not able to interact with the 'Disconnect' Button @Nandan

Comment: Hey, Sorry to have missed out some part.
Have updated the above answer :)

Comment: I tried to do exactly as you said but it is disabled as well. I have added that screenshot to the question. @Nandan

Comment: Hey @SulabhShrestha ,
I tried executing your above scenario and the cause is your account via which you have logged in to the ADF does not have access on the GIT repo which was used to configure.

I have edited my answer with the screenshots to prove the same.

Hope this resolves your queries

Comment: I got what you meant about the access stuffs but can you let me know how to "So I added my account to Repo and after some time I was able to manage the GIT in ADF" do this part? I am confused about the account part. I am logged in to ADF as an azure account (example@outlook.com) and not able to give access from GitHub(example@gmail.com) as the account(example@outlook.com) doesn't have a GitHub as its made specifically only for Azure services. in Summary, they are different accounts and the question is how to give access to the azure only account from GitHub.

Comment: Hey @SulabhShrestha , the one who had created this ADF initially would have access on the ADF as well as GitHub Repo. He/She can take over the configurations part.
In case if you want to try it out, you can try either ways of either adding the gmail account  as a guest user in your AAD and then giving it contributor access to the ADF or the other way round :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886174/how-can-i-give-access-to-a-private-github-repository

Answer (score 0):

On the home page of Azure Data Factory, can you see the option "**Git repo settings**" at the upper right corner? If yes, you can try to remove the GIT connection via this option.

Below are the tickets for the similar questions, you can reference:

- [**Enable Publishing in 'Data Factory' mode**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561402/enable-publishing-in-data-factory-mode)
- [**You are not allowed to make changes or publish from 'Data Factory' mode as your factory has GIT enabled**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60739834/you-are-not-allowed-to-make-changes-or-publish-from-data-factory-mode-as-your)

Comment: I can see that the previous versions had an option to remove the Git connection but there is none right now on the right-hand corner and on the homepage itself.

Comment: Hi @Sulabh Shrestha,
Thanks for your reply.
I noticed that **Nandan** also has shared some helpful suggestions in his answer. Have you checked it?
If his answer is helpful to you to solve the problem, you can mark it as the solution of this ticket. This may help more people who have the similar problems when they are looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issues as the OP. I have an username@mybusiness.itservices user on Azure and a myname@gmail private GitHub account, and it's impossible to invite the Azure user because they don't have an email (they are just for administering Azure resources).

Integration with GitHub: 1) didn't work at all when configured at the launch time of ADF, 2) worked for one session when created within a new ADF instance, and 3) doesn't work when logging back into ADF.

I get the exact same issues: cannot disconnect from git:

[image]

and can't change into Git mode to do any work in ADF:

[image]

Naturally, the GitHub account has ADF authorised but there's no collaborator on the repo because I can't invite a user who doesn't have email:

[image]

None of the linked resources deal with this issue because there's no way to disconnect Git from ADF unless the "disconnect" button is no longer greyed-out.  I would really appreciate any more ideas.

Comment: yes exactly @henryswift. I had the same problem. We need to upvote the question so that it will have the reach and we may get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself and was able to resolve it.  It occurred because the collaboration branch was deleted.  In the browser, I was unable to select Git mode because it was confused.

To fix it, I turned to PowerShell.  You need Powershell with the Az cmdlets installed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-5.3.0

You'll need to know:

- Subscription name in Azure
- Data Factory name
- Collaboration branch in github
- Root folder in github
- Account name for github
- Repository name in github

Fire up Powershell with the Azure cmdlets and do like so...

```
Connect-AzAccount
Set-AzContext "<yoursubscriptionname>"
$dataFactory = Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -Name "<your data factory name>"
Set-AzDataFactoryV2 -InputObject $dataFactory -CollaborationBranch "<branch>" -RootFolder "<github root folder>" -AccountName "<github account>" -RepositoryName "<github repository>" -HostName "https://github.com"
```

When I ran that series of Powershell commands, it asked me if I wanted to overwrite, I said yes.  Then I was able to deal with Git in Data Factory again.